# mogenerator doesn't generate the files

Tags: objective-c, core-data, xcode6, mogenerator

I've just installed mogenerator using one of tutorials. I have added run script to my new target, and clicked Cmd+B. I should get some new files, but i didn't. In my .xcdatamodeld i have 2 entities (User and Repos). Below you can find my print screen of my project.

[image: screen of my project just after build mogenerator using my new target]

Where is the problem in my thinking? What should i do more? Please, help me, because i haven't found the solution on the web yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all looks fine (judging by your screenshot).

One thing to check - which caused me the same issue - is that, when you've created your Entities in the **xcdatamodelId** file, make sure that you click on the Data Model Inspector icon, and that each entity has a `Name` value, and a matching "`Class`" value.

Miss out the `Class` name, and nothing will get generated.

[image]

Btw, when you click on Build, do you get a "Build succeeded" message ?

Here's the tutorial I followed to get mogenerator working:
[RaptureInVenice](http://raptureinvenice.com/getting-started-with-mogenerator/)

I should say, I've used *mogenerator* in a few projects, and this command line bit is always the piece that gives me trouble.  Sometimes, I have to select my **xcdatamodelId** file, and create a new Version of it, before mogenerator will use it.   But once it is working, it's a blessing.

Anything to avoid having to use the needlessly over-complicated CoreData stuff.

Someone should remind Apple that it's 2014...